# Laravel 5.2 return with errors - how to tell which form is submitted

Tags: php, laravel-5

I'm using Laravel 5.2. On my index page, I've got a button to add a new entry, which brings up the form in a lightbox. This form then submits via the create method.

I also have each entry listed on this page, with the ability to edit them inline, which submits via the update method.

I've setup validation via a Request. This means when someone misses something on the add, it redirects to the index method with errors. The errors only show though, when the lightbox is triggered by the user.

I know I can use `$errors` to see any errors, but I don't see how I can differentiate between the create and update forms for the sake of forcing the lightbox to appear on reload with create errors. Is there a way to do that?

Update:

Suggestion was made to use AJAX to bypass the reload issue, but now I'm getting a 422 return:

AJAX call:

```
(function(){
    var submitAjaxRequest = function(e){
        var form = $(this);
        var method = form.find('input[name="_method"]').val() || 'POST';

        $.ajax({
            type: method,
            url: form.prop('action'),
            data: form.serialize(),
            success: function(data){
                console.log(data)
            }
        });

        e.preventDefault();
    }
    $('form[data-remote]').on('submit', submitAjaxRequest);
})();
```

Request:

```
public function response(array $errors)
{
    $response = parent::response($errors);

    if ($this->ajax() || $this->wantsJson()) {
        return $response;
    }

    return $response->with('requestMethod', $this->method());
}
```

I've also tested the ajax call and it works fine when the validation rules are met. It only fails if the validation comes back with something incorrect in the input.

Comment: Can you please provide more information, code snippets for request, form and controller will be very useful.

Comment: Could you use `ajax`? This way you wouldn't have to worry about the reload.

Comment: @Ross Wilson - ajax might be the simplest solution by removing the problem. I'm wondering if there's another way to differentiate the forms before I run with it though..

Comment: @RossWilson - ajax isn't working because I'm using a request for validation, so when a required field isn't filled out I'm getting a `422 (Unprocessable Entity)` return instead of the expected error feedback

Comment: Add `error: function(response) { console.log(response);}` to you ajax call and you'll see how to access the errors.

Comment: only just saw last comment. this worked. I can pull the errors from the response there. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could override the `response` method so that you can flash the type of request.

In you `Request` class you could add

```
    public function response(array $errors)
{
    $response = parent::response($errors);

    if ($this->ajax() || $this->wantsJson()) {
        return $response;
    }

    return $response->with('requestMethod', $this->method());
}
```

(With ajax you wouldn't need to worry about the page reload so we can just return the original response.)

In the above I'm assuming you're using `POST` for your create methods and `PUT` or `PATH` for your update methods. If this is not the case you could use a way that make sense to you to differentiate between the requests.

Then in your view you could do something like:

```
@if(session('requestMethod') == 'POST')
```

https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/responses#redirecting-with-flashed-session-data

If you are going to use ajax, as I mentioned in the comment above, you will need to make sure you use the error method within the ajax call:

```
$.ajax({
    type: method,
    url: form.prop('action'),
    data: form.serialize(),
    success: function (data) {
        console.log('success', data)
    },
    error: function (data) {
        console.log('error', data)
    }
});
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: concept would do it, but I'm having problems implementing. I've copied your code into my `EntryRequest` file, below the rules()` function. I'm also using the correct restful `POST` & `PUT` methods for the forms. Still getting the 422 response. I also tried moving the `return $response;` out of the if statement to test and no change, with or without an ajax call.